# Different titles on different pages of an mdframed box

Tags: mdframed

I would like to have a titled mdframed box. The following works. But I would like the title on the second and subsequent pages to mention "Continued" along with the title [someting like Title (continued)].

How do I modify the example below to obtain this?

Vikas

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright,showtrims]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color,graphicx}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\usepackage[backgroundcolor=gray!40,roundcorner=8pt,skipabove=10pt,skipbelow=10pt,leftmargin=10pt,rightmargin=10pt,framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}

\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\newenvironment{icn2box}[1][]{%
\addcontentsline{box}{icn2boxes}{\protect\numberline #1}
\begin{mdframed}[%
frametitle={#1},
skipabove=\baselineskip plus 2pt minus 1pt,
skipbelow=\baselineskip plus 2pt minus 1pt,
linewidth=0.5pt,
roundcorner=8pt,
shadow=true,
frametitlerule=true,
repeatframetitle=true,
frametitlebackgroundcolor=White,
backgroundcolor=White,
]%
}{%
\end{mdframed}
}


\author{Draft: Do not Cite}
\date{\today}
\title{Title of the document}

\begin{document}


\begin{icn2box}[Summary: Long title here that wraps over two lines and some times three]
\label{box-icn2-appc1}


\lipsum

\lipsum

\lipsum

\lipsum

\lipsum

\lipsum

\end{icn2box}

\end{document}
```

Comment: please edit your code to be compilable (working)

Comment: Sorry, compiles without complaining now.